# How to design a Ticket to Ride fan expansion?

Tags: game-design, ticket-to-ride, expansions, game-development

I want to design a unofficial map for ticket to ride. Is there a known formula how to create one, basic ground rules on what makes a playable board? How many cities is playable? What percentage of grey vs colored tracks? How many total possible train positions is too few, and too many?

Comment: I think this question is fine.  As long as the answers come from folks with specific experience.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the folks at boardgamegeek.com have many excel tables for the current versions of the game with plenty of data you can try use to help you on your way

Answer (score -1):

Try analyzing your Ticket to Ride game that you already have and base your first expansion on that board. Measure the board, count how many of each color card there are in the deck, and count how many tracks there are of each color. I would model your first fan expansion after the base game without any add-ons, see if your expansion works, and then try making progressively more complicated fan expansions.

Answer (score -2):

Technically, no, and I'll have a much more complete answer for you tomorrow. I can tell you a bit about some of the design behind others though.
First off is the points:
1 = 1pt
2 = 2pt (+1)
3 = 4pt (+2)
4 = 7pt (+3)
5 = 10pt (+3)
6 = 15pt (+5?)
7 = 18pt (+3)
8 = 21pt (+3)
9 = 27pt (+6)

Then look into what makes travel in your area unique.
In Heart of Africa, the different colours represent different terrains which can provide bonus points.
Germany is about tourism.
Europe and Switzerland are often about traversing difficult terrain.

Either find a fun mechanic, or a way to demonstrate a unique thing on your map.